# How to get SSH running on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, openssh, sshd

I'm trying to get sshd running in my Kubernetes cluster so that I can set up a reverse proxy/ngrok tunnel per [this blog post](https://jerrington.me/posts/2019-01-29-self-hosted-ngrok.html).

I've got nginx running, but I can't seem to connect to SSH.

Here's the complete Kubernetes config:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-example-ingress
  namespace: dev-example
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - dev.example.ca
      secretName: dev-example-tls
  rules:
    - host: dev.example.ca
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: app-service
              servicePort: 80
          - backend:
              serviceName: app-service
              servicePort: 2222
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
  namespace: dev-example
spec:
  selector:
    pod: my-pod-label
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
    - name: ssh-tcp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 2222
#    - name: ssh-udp
#      protocol: UDP
#      port: 2222
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
  namespace: dev-example
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod: my-pod-label
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod: my-pod-label
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: dreg.example.ca/example/dev.example.ca
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
        - name: sshd
          image: linuxserver/openssh-server
          ports:
            - name: ssh
              containerPort: 2222
          env:
            - name: PUID
              value: '1000'
            - name: PGID
              value: '1000'
            - name: TZ
              value: America/Los_Angeles
            - name: USER_NAME
              value: example
            - name: USER_PASSWORD
              value: test
```

But when I try to connect it says "connection refused":

```
❯ ssh -p 2222 example@dev.example.ca
ssh: connect to host dev.example.ca port 2222: Connection refused
```

I don't know if that means I didn't expose the port properly or what.

I'm pretty sure [`linuxserver/openssh-server`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/openssh-server) is running on port 2222. If I run `ps -aux` in that container I get:

```
^@root@app-deployment-5d9567dcc5-f5hq6:/# ps -aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0    200     4 ?        Ss   19:26   0:00 s6-svscan -t0 /var/run/s6/services
root        34  0.0  0.0    200     4 ?        S    19:26   0:00 s6-supervise s6-fdholderd
root       277  0.0  0.0    200     4 ?        S    19:26   0:00 s6-supervise openssh-server/log
root       278  0.0  0.0    200     4 ?        S    19:26   0:00 s6-supervise openssh-server
mpen       280  0.0  0.0    256     4 ?        Ss   19:26   0:00 s6-log n30 s10000000 S30000000 T !gzip -nq9 /config/logs/openssh
mpen       281  0.0  0.0   4384  3480 ?        Ss   19:26   0:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D -e -p 2222 [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
root       298  0.5  0.0   2580  2304 pts/0    Ss   19:32   0:00 bash
root       307  0.0  0.0   1640   868 pts/0    R+   19:32   0:00 ps -aux
```

What am I missing?

I'm open to using other ssh docker images if they work better/are easier. This is just for dev.

Answer (score 2):

The ingress system only works for HTTP (some Ingress Controllers support basic TCP routing as a custom extension but you're just using the basics). SSH is not an HTTP-based protocol :) What you want instead is a Service with type LoadBalancer.

Comment: Hmm. So I'm using the nginx-ingress helm chart for my load balancer. I see there's a [`controller.service.customPorts` option](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/) there which I believe I can use to add SSH/port 22. But then what? Can I just add my service like I have above and it'll find it?

Comment: Just, just add `type: LoadBalancer` and it should work. You'll see the public IP in the service info.

Answer (score 1):

The Kubernetes `Ingress` resource is not meant to support TCP or UDP services. Nonetheless, some `Ingress` implementations provide mechanisms to support TCP or UDP on different ports. If you are using NGINX Ingress Controller, you can expose TCP or UDP ports by modifying `ConfigMaps`.

To configure NGINX Ingress Controller to use these `ConfigMaps` you need to configure them while deploying the Controller using the arguments `--tcp-services-configmap` and `--udp-services-configmap`. Each `ConfigMap` should already be available before deploying the Controller.

You can then define your custom ports by defining a map of ports to services.

For example, if you were defining the NGINX Ingress Controller through manifest files, you should configure the `DaemonSet` for the Controller like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  # metadata configuration...
spec:
  # spec configuration...
  containers:
    - image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:$TAG
      name: nginx-ingress-microk8s
      # container configuration...
      args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-tcp-services
        - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-udp-services
        # other arguments...
```

Here is an example of a `ConfigMap` taken directly from the docs:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  9000: "default/example-go:8080"
```

You can define any number of ports that can be exposed using this mechanic. However, I've never used this configuration with SSH to expose Syslog ports.